# Integer solutions to linear congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Please excuse my handwritten solution, but the way I did the problem is not what I am having trouble with. **The question asks for integer solutions to the linear congruence, are they asking for the congruences classes that I have boxed or something else?**

---

---

---

---

---

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: A little messy there in the middle, but the main stuff looks fine to me (though the solutions are modulo $\;125\;$ ....I don't know what that little $\;105\;$ there means) . So you have infinite solutions. For example, all integers $\;=3\pmod{125}: 3,\,128,\,253,\,378,\ldots\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio thank you for catching the modulo 125 error. So my answer describes all integer solutions?

Comment: I think it does, understanding that each equivalence class is in fact an infinite set of integers.

Comment: @DonAntonio thank you, If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You don't have to compute the value of  $7^{-1}$ mod $25$ in order to cancel $7$ from $\,7x\equiv 21\pmod{25}.\,$ You only need to know the inverse *exists*, then you can multiply both sides by $\,7^{-1}\,$ to cancel it, using $7^{-1}(7\cdot 3)\equiv 3.\,$ But by Bezout we know $7$ is invertible mod $25$ since $\,\gcd(7,25) = 1.\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Don't I need to multiply the 21 by 7^-1 which is 18?

Comment: @Allan $ 7^{-1}(21) \equiv 7^{-1}(7\cdot 3)\equiv 3\ $ so you really can *cancel*  $\,7\,$ without knowing the value of $\,7^{-1},\,$ only its existence.

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes I see now, thank you.